# how can I create a function that can post my parameters using curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I developed a API for my website. API working 100% correctly. But I designed it to catch and execute functions from this kind of POST parameters`$_POST['functionName'];` `$_POST['parameter'];` Now, in request page i want to send those as `$_POST`, I managed to do deal with that. But my problem is, **how can I create a function that can post my parameters** for each functions in API using `curl`. Here is my code which send requests to my **API**.

```
$url = 'http://localhost/myapi/api.php';
$postfields['functionName'] = "myFunction";
$postfields['parameter'] = "1";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$results = json_decode($data, true);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Can't you just wrap that code in a function declaration, take `$url` and `$postfields` as arguments and return `$results`? Also FYI passing `$postfields` through `http_build_query()` before passing it to cURL will result in much smaller and more efficient HTTP requests being sent.

Comment: Actually I want to pass `$postfields` to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);` I've tried to return that in a function. When i tried to return that that parameter no longer sent as a $_POST by `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Comment: Can you just post a sample function ?

Comment: So you don't mean something like [this](http://codepad.org/imxploSw) then? Can you clarify exactly what you want?

Comment: Cool... lemme check that... :) Looks like this should work.

Comment: THIS WORKS !!! <3 Thanks a lot <3